# Django - Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process

Tags: django, apache, raspberry-pi3

I'm using django (2.0.1) on Raspberry Pi 3 with DietPi on it. I've upgraded RPI today and got this error

```
[Fri Mar 02 08:29:57.741991 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1564:tid 1861219376] [client 127.0.0.1:60308] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'app': /home/user/app/app/wsgi.py, referer: http://app/
```

It worked well.

My config for apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    TimeOut 120

    ServerAdmin admin

    ServerName app
    ServerAlias app

    ErrorLog    /home/user/app/logs/error_log
    CustomLog   /home/user/app/logs/access_log common

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/app/app/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess appprocesses=6 python-path=/home/user/app:/home/user/app_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages header-buffer-size=65536 inactivity-timeout=300
    WSGIProcessGroup app

    <Directory "/home/user/app">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /robots.txt /home/user/app/static/robots.txt

    Alias "/static/admin/" "/home/user/app/root/admin/"
    <Location "/home/user/app/root/admin">
    SetHandler None
    </Location>

    Alias "/media/" "/home/user/app/media/"
    <Location "/home/user/app/media/">
    SetHandler None
    </Location>

    Alias "/static/" "/home/user/app/static/"
    <Location "/home/user/app/static/">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>

    <LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$">
        SetHandler None
    </LocationMatch>

    <Directory "/home/user/app" >
        WSGIProcessGroup terminal
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

my /home/user/app/app/wsgi.py is standard from django.

RPI connects trough USB0 to rfid-reader and because of this error I get a 500-error-page.

I don't know where am I wrong. I hope you can help.

Comment: I found the answer

Comment: Then please share it so other readers can get help too.

Comment: I setted timeout on 10 second and any errors disappeared...